# Error:Cause: com.android.sdklib.repository.FullRevision AS2.0

Tags: android, gradle

When I updated my AS to version 2.0, I cannot gradle-sync the project anymore.

**Can anyboby fix this? Thinks.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaaKF.png)

Comment: do you see a line written at the bottom of screenshot?. `Help|Show Log` and provide details given there for further clarification

Comment: see my answer and let me knw if it worked

Comment: 18:35:17 Gradle sync started
18:35:31 Gradle sync failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
18:35:32 Gradle sync started
18:35:35 Gradle sync failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add bellow function in your build.gradle in android section

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

Comment: Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.